# ORA-00904: invalid identifier en query INSERT

Tags: oracle, plsql

El siguiente error parte de insertar una serie de valores en una tabla, en donde todas sus columnas están bien definidas.

El fichero .xml alojado en la API:

```
<select id="selectdistribucion" resultType="string" parameterType="String" statementType="CALLABLE">
    SELECT LINEA FROM (
        SELECT  FILE_NAME_N43 ||';'|| REPLACE(EFFECTIVE_ACCOUNT_LIST,';',',') ||';'|| SEND_THROW_FLAG ||';'|| EMAIL AS LINEA, ROW_NUMBER() OVER
    (ORDER BY FILE_NAME_N43)
    AS RN
    FROM EXP_S3.N43_PARAMETRY_T
    WHERE
    1 = 1
    <if test="file_name">
         AND UPPER(FILE_NAME_N43) LIKE '%'||UPPER(#{file_name})||'%'
    </if>
    <if test="effective_account">
         AND UPPER(EFFECTIVE_ACCOUNT_LIST) LIKE '%'||UPPER(#{effective_account})||'%'
    </if>
    <if test="send_flag">
         AND UPPER(SEND_THROW_FLAG) LIKE '%'||UPPER(#{send_flag})||'%'
    </if>
    )
    WHERE RN BETWEEN #{firstRow} and #{lastRow}
    ORDER BY RN
</select>

<select id="insertDistribucion" resultType="string" parameterType="String" statementType="CALLABLE">
    INSERT INTO EXP_S3.N43_PARAMETRY_T (
      FILE_NAME_N43, 
      EFFECTIVE_ACCOUNT_LIST, 
      SEND_THROW_FLAG, 
      EMAIL
    )
    VALUES (#{fileName},#{accounts},#{flag},#{email})
</select>
```

Es obvio que he realizado las pruebas pertinentes en la BD Oracle, obteniendo el mismo tipo de error.

El error en cuestión...

> #### SQL: INSERT INTO EXP_S3.N43_PARAMETRY_T (FILE_NAME_N43, EFFECTIVE_ACCOUNT_LIST, SEND_THROW_FLAG, EMAIL)      VALUES (?,?,?, ?)
>
> #### Cause: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00904: "EMAIL": invalid identifier

Comment: Cuando creaste la tabla, ¿pusiste los nombres de las columnas entre comillas?

Comment: Y como sabemos si esa tabla tiene una columna email? porque ese es el error que marca

Answer (score 1):

No existe una columna EMAIL en esa tabla. Ejecuta la instrucción `DESCRIBE EXP_S3.N43_PARAMETRY_T`. Te dará entre otra información los nombres de las columnas. Después de eso, si el nombre de la columna es incorrecto, usa la instrucción `RENAME COLUMN` para establecer el nombre deseado. Por el contrario, si el nombre de la columna es correcto, modifica la sentencia INSERT para que incluya el nombre de columna correcto.